# Can a commercial pilot get paid by friend?

Tags: faa-regulations

'm a little bit headache about charge issue with commercial pilot certificate .hope someone help me figure out.

---

1. IF my friend approaches to me first and ask for a flight to somewhere using my airplane and I get paid for this flight,am I holding out?If I am,how can I do that legally?How about using his/her airplane?
2. According to [119.1(e)](https://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?SID=75f21ddf84befb36d3b2809175661a33&mc=true&node=se14.3.119_11&rgn=div8),can I hold out for those flights and get paid(Ferry,banner towing etc.)and get paid？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your friend approaches you and asks for a one-time ride, you're fine to charge for it. If you decide to advertise, or your friend tells a friend who tells a friend and word of mouth is that you offer an air taxi service, you are holding yourself out as a carrier and need to get a part 135 operating certificate.

Same thing with ferrying, banner towing, etc. If you are offering it to the general public as a service you need to get an operating certificate.

Comment: Thank you I got that.What if we decide to fly there every month,just once a month and he(same person each time)pay for me evey time.Is that also fine?Or I have to make a contract with him/her which called private carriage and also need a operating certificate?

Comment: Almost positive you don't need an operating certificate for private carriage.

Comment: Am I thinking too much?119.23(b)[link](https://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?SID=6b9d3fd2f5ac9bc433df45cd916f9bc6&mc=true&node=se14.3.119_123&rgn=div8)

Comment: If you are doing it once a month you may be pushing the envelope. Do you also need to go to that destination? Then you may be fine, but when the question delves into hazy in-betweens only your local FSDO can answer that question. However, I learned long ago, the hard way, that you don't tell the FAA what they don't need to know.

Comment: Your second paragraph is incorrect in the US. 14 CFR §119 explicitly allows you to do these things without an operating certificate. Some of the operations in 119 require a letter of authorization e.g. sight seeing, but none require an operating certificate.